# Connecting Twitter Social button to the referrer page

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

Is it possible to connect Twitter button to a referrer url, so that all twits will reference the page visitor has landed from instead of referencing the lending page itself?

I have done it with Facebook an G+, since both use a `href` within script and `<?php $ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];echo $ref;?>` to appoint `href` to the referee url, but cannot figure out what to do with Twitter since the script does not use `href` element inside.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?via=my_twitter_ID&amp;count=vertical" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.createElement(\'script\'), b = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0];
    a.type = \'text/javascript\';
    a.async = true;
    a.src = \'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\';
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b);
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Found the way around it, simply added `data-url="<?php $ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];echo $ref;?>"`